# change jobs/careers vs change my accounting job/my accounting career

Tags: sentence-construction

If you want to quit your job or career and choose to do something else, you can say:

(1) I want to change(or switch) jobs.

(2) I want to change(or switch) careers.

(3) I want to change my job.

(4) I want to change my career.

If you want to be specific about the **current** job or career you want to change, is it correct to say it in the following way?

(5) I want to change my accounting job.

(6) I want to change my accounting career.

Do (5) and (6) make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> (3) I want to change my job.
>
> (4) I want to change my career.

These don't quite mean what you intend. They mean "I would like to change (something about) my current job/career (but stay in the same job/career)".

To say that you want to move to a different company or field of work, **you would say**:

> I want to change jobs.
>
> I want to change careers.

Though grammatically correct, you would **not say**:

> (5) I want to change **accounting** jobs.
>
> (6) I want to change **accounting** careers.

Comment: I agree with Rykara  however would like to add some alternatives  for the last sentences. What you have written is not correct and is not the way you would go about stating your desires. Try these; 5) I want to stay in accounting but I would prefer a different/new job. 6) I want to get out of accounting and start a new career.